# Импорт функции в другом файле

Tags: javascript, функции

**Внимание!!! Благодаря [ссылки](https://learn.javascript.ru/currying-partials) вопрос решен, спасибо [ksa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/520359/ksa)**

Если коротко, то

```
в файле First.js

function curry(f) {
    return function (a) {
        return function (b) {
            return f(a, b);
        }
    }
}

let foo = curry(onAuthStateChanged);
let foo1 = foo(auth);

export { foo1 }

------------------------------------

в файле Second.js

import { foo1 }

foo1(user => {
   console.log(user); ---> значение user
})
```

Есть функция, которая импортируется из firebase-auth через CDN. Она показывает авторизован ли тек. пользователь или нет.

В одном файле, назовем его, First.js я ее импортирую, пар-р auth - инициализация сервиса аутен-ции.

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user)=>{
   if (user) {
      ...что-то делаю...
   } else {
      ...что-то делаю...
   }
})
```

**Вопрос в том, могу ли я как то экспортировать эту функцию уже со вставленным параметром auth?**

Что я делал:

- Первое

```
const foo = onAuthStateChanged;

export { foo }
```

В файле Second.js

```
import { foo } from "./First.js"
import { auth } from "./init.js"

foo(auth, (user)=>{

})
```

Это работает, но я не хочу тянуть auth из init.js

- Второе

```
const foo = onAuthStateChanged(auth);

export { foo }
```

В файле Second.js

```
import { foo } from "./First.js"

foo((user)=>{

})
```

Это не работает выдает ошибку

Прошу помощи у сообщества знающих людей.

Comment: Возможно тебе подойдет каррирование - https://learn.javascript.ru/currying-partials Оно как раз подходит под твое "второе"...

Comment: Спасибо, за ссылку. Буду изучать!

Comment: Да, это то  что нужно, еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> могу ли я как то экспортировать эту функцию уже со вставленным параметром auth?

Предложу вариант с каррированием функции `onAuthStateChanged`..

Если ее обернуть вот такой "оберткой" - можно будет "вставить" первый аргумент и уже  эту полученную функцию можно будет экспортировать.

Надеюсь комментарии в коде показывают что и как использовать.

```js
//
function onAuthStateChanged(auth, cb) {
  if (auth) console.log('auth есть')
  if (cb) console.log('cb есть')
}

let foo = curry(onAuthStateChanged)

// готовим "экспортную" функцию
foo = foo('auth')
// вот тереть это можно экспортировать

// применим закаррированое foo
foo('user')


//
function curry(func) {
  return function curried(...args) {
    if (args.length >= func.length) {
      return func.apply(this, args);
    } else {
      return function(...args2) {
        return curried.apply(this, args.concat(args2));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, еще раз

Comment: если достаточно одного параметра спереди намного проще `.bind` использовать @alexkolykhalov

Comment: А как? Есть пример?

Comment: @Grundy, насколько я читал про `bind` - это привязка к контексту... Иными словами что будет в `this` внутри функции. Но никак не про параметры.

Comment: @alexkolykhalov, вот статейка на тему "триады" `bind`, `call` и `apply` - https://habr.com/ru/articles/701040/

Comment: ok, спасибо буду изучать

Comment: @ksa, плохо читал. В данном случае контекст в функции не используется, а все параметры кроме первого становятся привязанными параметрами

Comment: @Grundy, как скажешь... Пример бы еще показал, так было бы еще лучше...

Comment: `let foo = onAuthStateChanged.bind(null, auth); foo('user')`